# ng-repeat not working, am I missing something?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've currently set this :

```
  $scope.privates = [
    {value:'Private'},
    {value:'Public'}
  ];
```

And in my view I do this :

```
%h2 Etablissement
  %div{"data-ng-repeat" => "private in privates"}
    %input{"data-ng-model" => "filterPrivacy[private.value]",:type => "checkbox"}
      {{private.value}}
```

And currently it renders this :

```
        <h2>Etablissement</h2>
        <div data-ng-repeat-start='private in privates'>
          <input data-ng-model='filterPrivacy[private.value]' type='checkbox'>
        </div>
```

the `{{private.value}}`isn't showing up anywhere and I should have two inputs cause I've got two values.
What am I missing ?
Cordially, Rob

P.S : When I test {{privates}} it renders this to me

```
<div ng-repeat='private in privates'>
   [{"value":"Private"},{"value":"Public"}]
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a issue in your rendered code, which should use `data-ng-repeat` instead of `data-ng-repeat-start`, if you change only this part, it works perfectly : http://jsfiddle.net/jjFzv/1/

If you want to use `data-ng-repeat-start` I think you should also include a `data-ng-repeat-end`

I also initialized the `$scope.filterPrivacy={};` in the controller, but I assumed you did it and it was not the main issue

With the data-ng-repeat-start/end it renders like this : http://jsfiddle.net/jjFzv/3/
Have fun

Comment: Thanks for taking time for the fiddle, it works perfectly ! Cheers !